# Question about vacuum state of fields in Quantum Field Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, vacuum

Are the fields in their empty state a single indivisible and static entity? I would also like to know if the gravitational field also has a vacuum state and if the other fields are permanently linked to it.
Regards

Comment: What do you mean by "single indivisible and static entity"? The vacuum state of a quantum field is the field with zero excitation, but there are fluctuations. Also, what do you mean by "gravitational field"? Is it the metric tensor or the Einstein tensor?

Comment: "single indivisible and static entity" means "fundamental entity" in the sense that it has no internal composition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields are "fundamental entities" whether there are particles or not: Particles are just excitations of fields. In their vacuum state quantum fields fluctuates according to Heisenberg uncertainty principle for time and energy. So the vacuum state of the gravitational field would be like seafoam (like Jean-Pierre Luminet's analogy). By definition of quantum fields in curved space-time, all the fields are "linked" to the gravitational field. But for the vacuum states, one has to be careful because the number of particles depends on the referential. So vacuum for an observer may not be the vacuum for another one.